# where can I download the full installer for Visual C++ Express?

Tags: installation, download, visual-studio

Is there any full installer for Visual C++ Express available? I want to download it at my workplace then install it back in home, but all I can find are web installers. It doesn't matter which version - 2008, 2010, 2012 RC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Visual Studio 2010 Express all-in-one ISO file here:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso

It contains standalone installers of the Visual Studio Express products (Visual Basic, C#, C++ and Web Developer).

Answer (score 1):

When searching for full installers, use the keywords "***offline***" and "***redistributable***".

Downloads with these in their name will be meant for installation in locations that do not have a network or internet connection, or in locations where you need to install it many times in a row and it doesn't make sense to go looking for a full download elsewhere.

Keeping that in mind, you can see that a Google search for [visual C++ offline installer](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual%20c%2B%2B%20offline%20installer) returns these two default Microsoft results, one of which is a search for "redistributable package" on Microsoft's own download page:

1. [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=redistributable%20package.)
2. [The Latest Supported Visual C++ Downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)